# How to check that the android plugin version is the same for both the project and imported module?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

in my project I used a class inside of my MainActivity class and it gives me the error: "Cannot Find Symbol "my class's name" even though I imported the the correct package. For some reason the import is not being used when I declare the class. I am not sure how to check how to make my Android Plugin version is the same for both: my Project and the Module I imported. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please add your `build.gradle` files to the question.

You can run the command: `gradlew app:dependencies` to see all dependencies with their versions